# Traversing ul parents and unchecking checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox, traversal

```
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label for="category_125" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="categories[]" value="125" id="category_125">Clothing</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="category_126" class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="126" id="category_126">Denim</label>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="category_127" class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="categories[]" value="127" id="category_127">Jeans</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="category_144" class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="144" id="category_144">Trousers</label>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="category_146" class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="146" id="category_146">Bermudas</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="category_152" class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="152" id="category_152">Sweaters</label>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="category_154" class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="154" id="category_154">Sweaters</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Given the above HTML code, let's say I click on 'Jeans' (the third input from the top, id="category_127"). I want to uncheck all inputs in its parents (Denim and Clothing).
I want to leave the siblings of Jeans as they are.
How can I do that using jQuery? There's an indefinite number of nested inputs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var checked = $this.prop("checked");
    if (!checked) {
        $this.parent().siblings("ul").find(":checkbox:checked").prop("checked", false);
    }

    if ($this.closest("ul").find(":checkbox:checked").not(this).length == 0) {
        $this.parents("ul").each(function() {
            if ($(this).siblings("ul").find(":checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
                $(this).siblings("label").children().prop("checked", checked);
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

It will uncheck parent's checkboxes only if there are no checked elements in parallel categories. For example, if "Trousers" and/or "Bermudas" are checked and you uncheck "Jeans", then "Clothes" won't be unchecked.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6EDw4/1/

Comment: Thank you, your code is a really good starting point. What you said about not unchecking Clothes is not true for me though, since leaving Clothing checked will show products from all Clothing subcategories (and I don't want that). I'll work on it today and see if I can fix it :) Thanks again

Comment: @koichirose In fact this was the very first answer: http://jsfiddle.net/6EDw4/. Maybe it will also help you.